# How to pry inside Google Dataflow / Apache Beam with Python

Tags: python, workflow, google-cloud-dataflow, development-environment, apache-beam

I'm building a dataflow runner that is going to clean files of JSON-as-strings from GCS and deliver them into a BigQuery table. This task is pushing the limits of what I understand about dataflow, and I'm frustrated by my inability to experiment on PCollections/Beam operations without running the entire pipeline.

My main question is: how does one develop with dataflow (python specific) without running the entire operation at once? Is there a way to step through each beam operation and actually view inside the PCollection to see what the transforms/custom methods are doing to the inputs?

For example -- I have the following custom class (borrowed from another SO post on parsing JSON in dataflow):

```
class JsonFileSource(filebasedsource.FileBasedSource):
    """A Beam source for JSON that emits all top-level json objects.
    Note that the beginning of a top-level json object is assumed to begin on a
    new line with no leading spaces, possibly preceded by a square bracket ([)
    or comma (,); and possibly with spaces between the bracket/comma and the
    beginning of the object.
    A custom source is necessary to enable parallelization of processing for
    the elements. The existing TextFileSource emits lines, but the Meteorite
    Landing data is a giant json array, where elements span multiple lines.
    """
    JSON_OBJECT_START = re.compile(r'^([\[,] *)?{')

    def read_records(self, file_name, offset_range_tracker):
        return self.obj_iterator(file_name, offset_range_tracker)

    @staticmethod
    def _iterable_gcs(f):
        """Create a generator for a not-quite-filelike object.
        FileBasedSource.open_file returns an object that doesn't implement the
        file interface completely, so we need this utility function in order to
        iterate over lines, while keeping the .tell() accurate.
        """
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            yield line

    def obj_iterator(self, file_name, offset_range_tracker):
        with self.open_file(file_name) as f:
            f.seek(offset_range_tracker.start_position() or 0)

            iterable_f = self._iterable_gcs(f)

            while True:
                current_pos = f.tell()
                # First, look for the start of an object
                # If we hit the end of the range allotted to us without finding
                # an element, stop.
                for line in iterable_f:
                    if self.JSON_OBJECT_START.match(line):
                        if not offset_range_tracker.try_claim(current_pos):
                            raise StopIteration()
                        content = [line.lstrip('[, ')]
                        break
                    current_pos = f.tell()
                else:
                    # We ran off the end of the file without finding a new
                    # object. This means we're done.
                    raise StopIteration()

                # We're in an object. Collect its contents and emit it.
                for line in iterable_f:
                    content.append(line)
                    if line.startswith('}'):
                        yield json.loads(''.join(content))
                        break
```

I then simply want to output this JSON to a new file in GCS to view it, however it's outputting a blank file. That code is as follows:

```
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    lines = p | 'Read JSON' >> beam.io.Read(JsonFileSource(known_args.input))
    output = lines
    output | WriteToText(known_args.output)
```

I'd really just like to step into/pry into the process and try different methods to format my results. How does everyone else develop with dataflow?

Comment: You can't. My advice is to make sure the pieces work on their own (write unit tests), and then run the pipeline when you're convinced it was pieced together correctly. I can't imagine it taking more than a few minutes for anything lesser than 5-10M records.

Comment: thanks for the comment @coldspeed, you're correct the job takes ~2 minutes to run which includes setup and teardown. I'm not a fan of the stop-n-go workflow, just hoping I could manipulate the objects & step through in real time.

Comment: It isn't easy, because the setup and resources are expensive and are usually allocated on a need-to basis. Breakpoints do not work well with this setup. You may be instead interested with pyspark which works on the concept of resilient distributed datasets...

Comment: At a basic level you can add logging to your pipeline and watch it in the console or there is also a stackdriver monitoring integration (requires payment). There's the concept of `metrics` which are currently a bit limited in Python but you can add them to inputs and see for example how many elements are coming in.